# Is there a better way to use dependency injection with generic DAO that has a third party library object as an argument in the methods

Tags: architecture, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dao

i think this is the first time i've not been able to find the answer to my question just by searching.

I'm doing some prototypes for a remake of our company system and i hit upon a problem i can't seem to get my head around.

I'm trying to utilise a reasonably generic DAO coupled dependency injection.
The problem i'm having is that i'd like to use a third party library for query definition within the method of the interface.

An example

```
public interface TestDAO<TEntity>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// get ALL the things
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs a supplied "where" clause and returns ALL the matched results
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(Specification<TEntity> specification);
}
```

Specification in this case is an object from a third party library called LinqSpecs.

It is my understanding that by doing this i'm essentially forcing a dependency on the third-party library on any implementation of the interface.

I understand that I can just forego using the library but if possible i'd like to keep it, at least until we've assessed its usefulness.

My question is, is there a way of doing this(or something similar) without dragging the third party dependency with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actitually want to give your interface TestDAO a searchfilter that can be hidden behind your own interface

```
    public interface TestDAO<TEntity>
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(ISearchFilter<TEntity> specification);
    }

    public interface ISearchFilter<TEntity>
    {
    }
```

The searchfilter implementation contains the actual data

```
    public class LinqSpecsSearchFilter : ISearchFilter<TEntity>
    {
        Specification<TEntity> specification;
    }
```

The downside of this aproach is that
your TestDAO implementation must do some ugly casting to get the LinqSpecs.Specification

Comment: I had thought of something along these lines but instead using lamda's directly.    
Am I correct in thinking that using this method, ISearchFilter is an interface defined in this assembly and the cast from ISearchFilter to Specification would be done in the implementing assembly?

Comment: if you mean `using lamda's directly. ` = `FindAll(Object specification);` that would do the job as well but is a little bit less typesave. Your are right. the interfaces go into one assembly and casting is done in the implementing assemly

Comment: I was actually thinking more along the lines of `FindAll (Func<TEntity,Bool> Specification)` which should give me a reasonable amount of type safety with something like `FindAll(x => x.Id == arg)`.  Creating a wrapper and an adapter for conversion might be more work than its worth, but it is a viable solution to my problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add extension method, and if someone is going to use `Specification`, he will get `LinqSpec` dependency in addition

```
namespace Dao
{
    public interface TestDAO<TEntity>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// get ALL the things
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    }

namespace DaoExtensions
{
    public static class TestDAOExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Runs a supplied "where" clause and returns ALL the matched results
        /// </summary>
        publicc static IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(this TestDAO<TEntity> dao, 
                                                    Specification<TEntity> specification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but this seems similar to the example in that you'd still force the third-party dependency to the implementing assembly.   
  
Edit: Also wouldn't this negate the benefits of DI as the extension method is now concrete?  
  
Edit: (not sure how to add line breaks to this, double space is not working hmmm)